# jQuery Plugin this.attr("id") undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Why is the call to `console.log(this.attr("id"));` coming up as undefined?

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.fs_suggest = function(options) {
        console.log(this.attr("id"));
    };
})( jQuery );

$("#places_search").fs_suggest();
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="search_container" id="search">
    <form data-remote="false" method="get" action="/search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="search places" name="query" id="places_search">
        <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get a reference to the element on which the .fs_suggest() function is called, in this case $("#places_search")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. The problem was that I didn't place the call to fs_suggest() in a doc ready block. So the answer is to call it like this.

places.js.coffee:

```
$ ->    
    $("#places_search").fs_suggest()
```

and in another file the plugin:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.fs_suggest = function(options) {
        console.log(this.attr("id"));
    };
})( jQuery );
```

now "this" will be seen, and will equate to $("#places_search").

Answer (score 8):

I think you want this:

```
console.log($(this).attr("id"));
```

Unless I'm mistaken, `this` refers to a DOM element (which doesn't have an `attr` function), whereas `$(this)` fetches the actual jQuery object (which does).

---

If this (or do I mean `this`? hehehe...) doesn't work then you're simply calling the function on an incorrect selector.

---

Upon further perusal of the jQuery docs, it would appear that your problem lies elsewhere outside of the context you have provided us. Are you calling your plugin before the DOM has loaded properly? (e.g. outside of `$(document).ready()`)

Comment: that's also undefined. it's spoken against doing that in the jquery plugin documentation itself // there's no need to do $(this) because
    // "this" is already a jquery object

    // $(this) would be the same as $($('#element'));

Comment: but how you do it then inside an .each or a .click event?

Comment: @masterkrang - Note that `this` will not be a jQuery object.

Comment: @masterkrang: I've edited my answer. Are you calling your plugin before the DOM has fully loaded?

Comment: @Elliot, it's incorrect to say that "$(this) fetches the actual jQuery object". More accurately, $(this) calls jQuery on the object--effectively a cast. While $(this).attr('id') should work, $(this).prop('id') is preferrable--ID is part of the HTML spec, so prop() is more accurate and faster.

Comment: @Christopher: While you're technically correct, I think you're missing the forest for the trees. :-)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Always a possibility. :)

Comment: @masterkrang: Yes, I already read that, that's why I updated my answer.

Comment: good point @ElliotBonneville i wasn't calling it in doc ready. now i am and getting the same error. must be minor typo, just sorta fried and can't find it.

Comment: @Derek check out the link i posted, it says that "this" should refer to a jquery object.

Comment: @masterkrang - But if you show it in the console, it shows that it is a DOM element.

Comment: @Derek: If you're logging `this` in the plugin, the console will show it as a DOM element inside a jQuery object. It's just that *some* consoles will display the jQuery object as though it was an Array, so it may look like `[<input type="text"...>]`

Comment: i fixed it. i think it had to do with calling the .fs_suggest() function within the document ready function. perhaps it didn't have enough time to init.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% what is being produced by this notation:

```
$.fn.fs_suggest = function(options) {
...
```

But if `$.fn` resolves to an Object and `fs_suggest` is an property of that Object, then the `this` inside the function would refer to that object and not a DOM element or jQuery wrapped element.

Comment: `$.fn` is a reference to the prototype object of the constructor. The method is being called on a jQuery object returned from the constructor, and so `this` will be a reference to that jQuery object. If the selector was successful, the object will contain a wrapped element.